# Spyder debugger hangs up on import influxdb_client

Tags: debugging, spyder, influxdb-python

When I try to run a script in debug mode, the Spyder debugger hangs up on the first line, even though the first breakpoint isn't until line 162. It doesn't seem to be frozen, it's just not progressing to the next line in the terminal:

debugfile('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/processDataV02.py', wdir='C:/Users/----------/OneDrive - -------/Documents/DAC-X (doc)/data')

> c:\users-------------\onedrive - ------------\documents\dac-x (doc)\data\processdatav02.py(1)()
> ----> 1 from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
> 2 import pandas as pd
> 3 import numpy as np
> 4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 5 from scipy import integrate

!continue

The problem seems to be with the import influxdb_client line - when I comment out this line the debugger works fine. However, without this line I can't pull the data that forms the basis of the analysis script. I need to be able to debug with the import influxdb_client line. Has anyone experienced similar issues?

I tried to debug the file in Spyder. The debugger hangs up on the first line (import influxdb_client as InfluxDBClient) instead of allowing me to debug. I have already tried updating to the latest version of Spyder. Restarting the kernel also does not help.